# ODATA as an icCube data source

Tags: odata, iccube

I am trying to load open data from the Dutch government. The data comes with a specific format that is specified in the pdf document you will find when searching on "Handleiding CBS Open Data Services".

What needs to be done to link to an open data source within icCube? Is this something specific (required new functionality) or can this be done with one of the existing datasources?

Answer (score 0):

For the time being even though we support some json databases (e.g. MongoDB) there is no direct ODATA support.

It's possible to develop your own datasource. Excel plugin is an example of this.